# Aurelia binding CSS class

Tags: aurelia

I have an HTML element within a repeater where I want to change the class based on four conditions. The condition is based on a attribute from JSON. The attribute is called `type`, and the css classes I am working with are `red`,`blue`,and `green`.The conditions are:

1. If `type` = red then assign css class `red`
2. If `type` = blue  then assign css class `blue`
3. If `type` = green  then assign css class `green`
4. If `type` is not defined or null  then assign css class `red`

With my limited experience with AngularJS I know that I can set a conditional CSS using the `ng-style` attribute. How would I achieve this using Aurelia?

Sample HTML markup

```
<div repeat.for="item of projects" class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="card-header">
        <!-- I want to change the css class red based on the value of the JSON attribute type -->
        <div class="component-type red">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: ey bb, be a bro and show my answer some love eh?

Comment: you're a gentleman and a scholar. you've done the world a tremendous service this day.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Use string interpolation on the class element.

```
<div repeat.for="item of projects">
  <div class="${item.type || 'red'}">...</div>
</div>
```

See working Ninja Turtle gist here: https://gist.run/?id=3a588b94a6b8d12666ba4f64645270aa

Comment: this is the best answer to any question on stack overflow ever

Comment: @MatthewJamesDavis, gist is not working. Can you check it out?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do:

```
<div repeat.for="item of projects" class="col-lg-6">
<div class="card-header">
    <!-- I want to change the css class red based on the value of the JSON attribute type -->
    <div class="component-type ${ item.type == undefined ? 'red' : item.type}">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
...
```

Or you could create a value converter:

```
export class TypeColourValueConverter {
  toView(value) {
    let colour = value;
    if (value === undefined) {
        colour = red;
    };

    return colour;
  }
}
```

Which you could then use like so:

```
<div repeat.for="item of projects" class="col-lg-6">
<div class="card-header">
    <!-- I want to change the css class red based on the value of the JSON attribute type -->
    <div class.bind='item.type | TypeColour'>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried that but it does not work. When I am looking at the DOM I do not see the class added. I think part of the issue, is that my JSON is coming from two different sources. One has the `type` attribute while the other does not, hence the fourth condition. I am able to see the type value by adding this to my code: `<span if.bind="!item.type">Is not defined</span>`

Comment: I think the answer just forgot some quotes around `'red'` - did you check the console for errors? This should work fine

Comment: The only issue I am seeing is an `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input`. I am seeing this error before and after adding the `${item.type}` value. I do not have control over the JSON I receive, so I might need to talk to my team to see if I can get it fixed.

Comment: https://gist.run/?id=a4fbc6d001f59ff546aa88f8c8d96bc8 here's a gist showing it running (check out app.js and change the value of `someJson.value` if you want to see the css class change). It does sound like a non-Aurelia issue.